# Unable to access firebase emulator UI

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have the following firebase.json

```js
{
  "emulators": {
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 4000
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't access localhost:4000.
My firebase-tools version is 8.4.3.
Running `firebase emulators:start` shows the following:

```js
i  emulators: Starting emulators: firestore, database
⚠  firestore: Did not find a Cloud Firestore rules file specified in a firebase.json config file.
⚠  firestore: The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
⚠  database: Did not find a Realtime Database rules file specified in a firebase.json config file. The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration.
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your apps. │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ localhost:8080 │
├───────────┼────────────────┤
│ Database  │ localhost:9000 │
└───────────┴────────────────┘
  Other reserved ports:
```

Thank you in appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake of not choosing a default project.
With a chosen default project, the emulator ui came up.

Comment: eleborate some more please

Comment: how did you choose a default project please?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in firebase.json , ui is set to true for emulators like below

```
"emulators": {
   "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
     },
    "ui": {
    "enabled": true
}, }
```

Then once you run emulator with "firebase emulator:start"

You will find

[image]

If you visit mentioned url in browser, you will find

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using docker for the emulator and trying to access it from the host using port mappings, make sure to set the `host` property of the emulator UI config to `0.0.0.0`. This goes for all other services you want to access from the host as well.

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "ui": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 4000
    },
    // other services
}
```